# WCF Streamed transfer mode for ordinal data

Tags: c#, wcf

I would like to ask, does TransferMode = Streamed have any influence if operation does not return or take arguments of type Stream?

If yes, how client can possibly start to process for example XML serialized class if it's not completely delivered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the first question, I think you'd benefit from one of those CodeProject examples that shows how to implement streaming over WCF. Just switching the TransferMode=Stream does not make streaming happen. If you don't have your code written for streaming (in .NET, implementing a FileStream to send your data), you'll still be buffering your payloads from one spot to another.  Here's a link to a relatively simple version: http://bartwullems.blogspot.de/2011/01/streaming-files-over-wcf.html

As far as the client response is concerned, from my experience, the client doesn't start processing the streaming content until the content is fully delivered, so there's no chance of you processing a half-full XML file by mistake.